# ORA-00907: Missing Right Parenthesis On Creating Foreign Key Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, sqlplus, ddl

### I Want To Make a Table Which Include One Auto Generated Primary Key And Two Foreign Keys But I'm Facing This Error...

```
create table answers
( id number generated by default on null as identity primary key
, question_id number foreign key references questions(id)
, user_id number foreign key references users(id)
, answer varchar(1000)
, post_date date);

create table answers (id number generated by default on null as identity primary key, question_id number foreign key references questions(id), user_id number foreign key references users(id), answer varchar(1000), post_date date)
```

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

### Then, I tried this:

```
create table answers
( id number generated by default on null as identity primary key
, question_id number foreign key (question_id) references questions(id)
, user_id number foreign key (user_id) references users(id)
, answer varchar(1000)
, post_date date );

create table answers
( id number generated by default on null as identity primary key
, question_id number foreign key (question_id) references questions(id)
, user_id number foreign key (user_id) references users(id)
, answer varchar(1000)
, post_date date )
                                                                                                     *
```

> ERROR at line 1:
>   ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

### It is still Giving Same Error!

But, if I do it in two steps:

```
create table answers
( id number generated by default on null as identity primary key
, question_id number not null
, user_id number not null
, answer varchar(1000)
, post_date date );

Table created.

alter table answers
add foreign key (question_id) references questions(id) add foreign key (user_id) references users(id);
```

> Table altered.

Can anyone please get me out of this?

Comment: `varchar` is missing the `2`.

Comment: `VARCHAR` is a valid type in Oracle - [docs here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50950) and search for "VARCHAR datatype" - and is currently synonymous with `VARCHAR2`, but its use is not recommended because Oracle says they're going to change it to use "different comparison semantics" - i.e. it'll probably take on the characteristics of the ANSI VARCHAR type. On the other hand, they've been promising that since at least Oracle 8 so I'm not holding my breath but, y'know, some day... :-)

Answer (score 4):

When defining the constraint in-line as part of the column definition you don't need to say `foreign key`:

```
create table answers
( id number generated by default on null as identity primary key
, question_id number references questions(id)
, user_id number references users(id)
, answer varchar(1000)
, post_date date);
```

Best of luck.

Comment: Also the datatype is optional ;)

Comment: Also you can optionally assign a name by adding `constraint constraintnamehere` at the start.

Answer (score 1):

you may define foreign keys at the bottom, non-adjacent to column names, like below :

```
create table answers (
                      id number generated by default on null as identity primary key, 
                      question_id number, 
                      user_id number, 
                      answer varchar(1000), 
                      post_date date,
                      foreign key(question_id) references questions(id),
                      foreign key(user_id) references users(id)                            
                     );
```

Comment: I prefer inline foreign key references, when the reference uses only one key.

Comment: @GordonLinoff i agree, Bob's answer is more brief, better.

Comment: Even so, there is nothing wrong with showing the alternative way to define constraints. It would be so good if all developers understood "inline" and "out-of-line" constraints, the similarities and differences, when to use one vs. the other, and that the syntax may sometimes be different. Then there would be far less confusion, and fewer questions like this.

Comment: I wouldn't *reject* ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT either. It becomes handy when there are tables that are mutually constrained by foreign keys. So, if you keep them in- or out-of-line, CREATE TABLE would fail as there's no that "other" table which, on the other hand, requires "this" table to be created. (When does that happen? When data model "grows", by adding table-by-table as requirements change; when you're about to create the final data model, ALTER TABLE is the savior). So, if you create tables without any constraints and enforce them later , everything would be just fine.