# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis 00907. 00000

Tags: sql, oracle, entity-framework

[image: Query]

```
create table SalesFact
(CalendarKey INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Calendar,
BranchKey INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Branch,
ProductKey INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Product,
SalesClerkKey INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES SalesClerk,
TID CHAR(15),
TimeofDay TIME,
DollarsSold NUMBER(10,2),
UnitsSold NUMBER (5),
PRIMARY KEY (ProductKey, TID));
```

Tried a few methods but to no avail, where did I go wrong?

[image: Error]

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
create table SalesFact
(CalendarKey INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Calendar,
BranchKey INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Branch,
ProductKey INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Product,
SalesClerkKey INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES SalesClerk,
TID CHAR(15),
TimeofDay TIME,
DollarsSold NUMBER(10,2),
UnitsSold NUMBER (5),
PRIMARY KEY (ProductKey, TID))
Error report -
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Thank you.

Comment: With you first attempt, can you just remove the words, `FOREIGN KEY`, from your DDL?  Look at Bob Jarvis' answer here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045336/ora-00907-missing-right-parenthesis-on-creating-foreign-key-oracle-12c?rq=1

Comment: By the way, Oracle uses `VARCHAR2` for character strings. CHAR is a fixed-length type that is not generally useful for general string columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
SQL> create table SalesFact
  2  (CalendarKey   INT NOT NULL  REFERENCES Calendar,
  3   BranchKey     INT NOT NULL  REFERENCES Branch,
  4   ProductKey    INT NOT NULL  REFERENCES Product,
  5   SalesClerkKey INT NOT NULL  REFERENCES SalesClerk,
  6   TID           CHAR(15),
  7   TimeofDay     DATE,
  8   DollarsSold   NUMBER(10,2),
  9   UnitsSold     NUMBER (5),
 10   PRIMARY KEY (ProductKey, TID)
 11  );

Table created.
```

- remove `FOREIGN KEY`
- there's no `TIME` datatype; use `DATE`

---

Apart from that, it is a good habit to name constraints. Primary keys don't allow `NULL` values so you can omit `NOT NULL` for those columns. For example:

```
SQL> create table SalesFact
  2  (CalendarKey   INT constraint fk_sf_cal
  3                       REFERENCES Calendar (calendarkey)
  4                       NOT NULL,
  5   ProductKey    INT constraint fk_sf_prod
  6                       REFERENCES Product (productkey),
  7   TID           CHAR(15),
  8   constraint pk_sf PRIMARY KEY (ProductKey, TID)
  9  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Comment: OMG, Thats a great help!! was following a lecture slides and was wondering where i've gone wrong from the lecture notes!
realized now that there's no such datatype as "time"!

Comment: I'm glad if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `FOREIGN KEY` keywords in an inline constraint, just the `REFERENCES` keyword and you also should be explicit and tell it what column of the table you are referencing.

Oracle doesn't have a `TIME` data type. If you just want the time of day then you should use `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` but if you want date and time then use the `DATE` data type.

You can also get into good habits and name your constraints rather than having to decode the system generated constraint names when you have an error.

```sql
create table SalesFact(
  CalendarKey   INT
                CONSTRAINT SalesFact__CalendarKey__NN NOT NULL
                CONSTRAINT SalesFact__CalendarKey__FK REFERENCES Calendar ( other_id ),
  BranchKey     INT
                CONSTRAINT SalesFact__BranchKey__NN NOT NULL
                CONSTRAINT SalesFact__BranchKey__FK REFERENCES Branch( branch_id ),
  ProductKey    INT
                CONSTRAINT SalesFact__ProductKey__NN NOT NULL
                CONSTRAINT SalesFact__ProductKey__FK REFERENCES Product ( product_id ),
  SalesClerkKey INT
                CONSTRAINT SalesFact__SalesClerkKey__NN NOT NULL
                CONSTRAINT SalesFact__SalesClerkKey__FK REFERENCES SalesClerk ( sales_id ),
  TID           CHAR(15),
  TimeofDay     INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND,
  DollarsSold   NUMBER(10,2),
  UnitsSold     NUMBER (5),
  CONSTRAINT SalesFact__ProductKey__TID__PK PRIMARY KEY (ProductKey, TID)
);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0143358dfd469ad6ec8dd71d47e3748b)*

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use following syntax

```
CREATE TABLE SalesFact
(
  CalendarKey      INT NOT NULL,
  BranchKey        INT NOT NULL,
  ProductKey       INT NOT NULL,
  SalesClerkKey    INT NOT NULL,
  TID              CHAR (15),
  TimeofDay        DATE,
  DollarsSold      NUMBER (10, 2),
  UnitsSold        NUMBER (5),
  CONSTRAINT fk_CAlendarKey FOREIGN KEY (CalendarKey)
    REFERENCES Calendar (PKID),
  CONSTRAINT fk_BRANCHKEY FOREIGN KEY (BranchKey) REFERENCES Branch (PKID),
  CONSTRAINT FK_PRODUCTKEY FOREIGN KEY (ProductKey) REFERENCES PRODUCT (PKID),
  CONSTRAINT fk_salesClerkKey FOREIGN KEY (SalesClerkKey)
    REFERENCES SalesClerk (PKID),
  PRIMARY KEY (ProductKey, TID)
)
```