# "missing right parenthesis" - 00907. 00000

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, create-table, ora-00907

```
CREATE TABLE Sale_FactTable 
(EmpID NUMBER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Employee_Dimension(EmpID),
ProductNum NUMBER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Product_Dimension(ProductNum),
SupplierNum NUMBER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Supplier_Dimension(SupplierNum),
SaleID NUMBER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES SALE(SaleID),
ClerkID NUMBER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Sale_Clerk_Dimension (ClerkID),
ProductID NUMBER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Product_Dimension(ProductID),
BranchID NUMBER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Branch_Dimension(BranchID),
LineID NUMBER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Sale_Line_Item_Dimension(LineID),
CustomerID NUMBER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Customer_Dimension(CustomerID),
SaleDate Date FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Sale_Line_Item_Dimension(SaleDate));
```

---

```
Error:
Error starting at line : 60 in command -
CREATE TABLE Sale_FactTable 
(EmpID NUMBER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Employee_Dimension(EmpID),
ProductNum NUMBER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Product_Dimension(ProductNum),
SupplierNum NUMBER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Supplier_Dimension(SupplierNum),
SaleID NUMBER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES SALE(SaleID),
ClerkID NUMBER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Sale_Clerk_Dimension (ClerkID),
ProductID NUMBER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Product_Dimension(ProductID),
BranchID NUMBER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Branch_Dimension(BranchID),
LineID NUMBER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Sale_Line_Item_Dimension(LineID),
CustomerID NUMBER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Customer_Dimension(CustomerID),
SaleDate Date FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Sale_Line_Item_Dimension(SaleDate))
Error report -
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: I changed the tags. The "ORA-00907" error is for Oracle, not MySQL. Also `NUMBER` is an Oracle data type, not recognized by MySQL.

Comment: You are mixing up syntax. Take out all the `FOREIGN KEY` text; or build the FKs separately to the column definitions.

Comment: Hi, please provide some description when you post a question. BTW, this is a very common problem (ORA-00907). This post has a robust set of answers for this problem, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045336/ora-00907-missing-right-parenthesis-on-creating-foreign-key-oracle-12c?rq=1.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to declare inline foreign keys is:

```
<column_name> <datatype> references <parent_table(parent_column_name)>
```

So basically this:

```
empid number foreign key references employee_dimension(empid)
```

Should be written:

```
empid number references employee_dimension(empid)
```

Alternatively, you can declare the foreign keys in a separate clause, which gives you a chance to choose the name of the key (as opposed to the inline syntax, where the name is automatically chosen by the database):

```
empid number,
constraint empid_fk foreign key references employee_dimension(empid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as

```
CREATE TABLE sale_facttable
(
   empid         NUMBER    REFERENCES employee_dimension (empid),
   productnum    NUMBER    REFERENCES product_dimension (productnum),
   suppliernum   NUMBER    REFERENCES supplier_dimension (suppliernum),
   saleid        NUMBER    REFERENCES sale (saleid),
   clerkid       NUMBER    REFERENCES sale_clerk_dimension (clerkid),
   productid     NUMBER    REFERENCES product_dimension (productid),
   branchid      NUMBER    REFERENCES branch_dimension (branchid),
   lineid        NUMBER    REFERENCES sale_line_item_dimension (lineid),
   customerid    NUMBER    REFERENCES customer_dimension (customerid),
   saledate      DATE    REFERENCES sale_line_item_dimension (saledate)
);
```